# FullCalendar js add event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to dynamicly add an event to my calendar

From the documentation i have gathered the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calendar/findEvents',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax'
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event
         [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d)
        }]
        );

    }
});
```

However this does not seem to work.

i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined fullcalendar.min.js: 6
```

Can anyone tell me what i am missing or what i am doing wrong in order to add an event to my calendar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass an object, and add true to fix the new event in the calendar :

```
var myevent = {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, d)};
$('.calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myevent, true);
```